# Accessing nested JSON data in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, drop-down-menu, nested

Link to app: https://boiling-coast-12353.herokuapp.com/

Bear in mind this is for an assignment that does not require components yet (but will)
What I have so far works, but now I would like to transform my data by using a nested JSON.
Currently so I have JSON data that looks like this:

```
[
    { "label": "Argentina", "percentage": 10.44 },
    { "label": "Bolivia", "percentage": 51.62 },
     etc..
]
```

which I access to generate buttons and generates divs for each object in the array respectively:

```
{
  this.state.data.map((data, index) => (
  <button key={index}className="button-primary" onClick={() => 
  {this.onChooseCountry(index);}}>
     <span className="btn-content" tabindex="-1">
     </span>{data.label}</button>
  ))
} 

{
  this.state.chosenCountries.map((chosenCountry, index) => (
  <div className="bar--show bar" style={{height: chosenCountry.percentage + "%"}}>

  <h3>{chosenCountry.label}</h3>
  <h4>{chosenCountry.percentage} %</h4>
  <button className="remove-btn" onClick={() => this.removeCountry(index)}>remove</button>

 </div>
   ))
 }
```

The new data set I'd like to work with I've organized like this:

```
[
    { 
    "year": "2010",
     "info": [
        { "Country": "Argentina", "Percentage": 10.44 },
        { "Country": "Bolivia", "Percentage": 51.62 },
          ...
    ]
    },
    {
    "year":"2011",
    "info": [
        { "Country": "Argentina", "Percentage": 10.34 },
        { "Country": "Bolivia", "Percentage": 51.62 },
    ...
```

And I would like to pass the year/label for array into a select drop down menu:

```
<select onChange={this.updateYear} id="select" className="YearChooser-select">
   <option value="">Select Year</option>
   <option value="2016">2016</option>
   <option value="2015">2015</option>
   <option value="2014">2014</option>
   ...

</select>
```

Method Im using so far that gets the year value from the dropdown:

```
updateYear = (ev) => {

    this.setState({
      year: ev.target.value },
      () => console.log('update year', this.state.year));

  }
```

I figured out how to access the new nested data set using sub, but I don't know how to link the selected year from the drop down menu to the info for each year:

```
{
  this.state.data.map((datum) =>
  <div>
    {datum.year}
  <ul>
    {datum.info.map((sub) =>
    <div>
      {sub.Country} : 
       {sub.Percentage} %
    </div>
    )}
  </ul>
  </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const options = this.state.data.map((datum) => (
    <option value={datum.year}>{datum.year}</option>
);

<select onChange={this.updateYear} id="select" className="YearChooser-select">
   {options}
</select>
```

is this what you looking for?

Comment: this looks good! only problem is when i try the code it says datum and options are undefined. I've tried adding the const = options... to the JSX, after the the render() and even in the method but I still keep getting the error. Tried adding options to the initial state and setStates too but no luck. I've never defined a variable while using the map function, so maybe there's something that went over my head here. I appreciate your answer though, it does make sense to me.

Comment: @NicolHawkins did you manage to get it work?

put this code inside the render method  outside of the return call
`const options = this.state.data.map((datum) => (
    <option value={datum.year}>{datum.year}</option>
);`

Comment: @NicolHawkins if you find my answer helpful would you mind to mark it as the answer. that would be cool :D

Comment: sure thing! my instructor has informed me that I should go with one of the other data sets I hand coded because it will be easier, but Im going to definitely save that line of code your wrote for my notes